# Image stays stuck in the upper left-hand corner in CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I have the following in-line style code:

```
<style>
.quote {
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    top: 250px;
    left: 500px;
    text-align: center;
};

#apple{
    position: absolute;
    top: 3000px;
    left: 600px;
}

#random{
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 500px;
}
```

and I'm trying to get the image with the apple id to move to a location different from where it's currently situated, which is in the upper left hand corner. Changing the coordinates of the other images and divs works fine, and I've experimented with changing the position of the apple image from fixed to absolute to relative and haven't found anything which allows me to move it to the center of the page.

Comment: please show us your html

Comment: <body>
<img id = "apple" src = "C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/apple.jpg" alt = "Apple" style="width:304px;height:228px">
<img id = "random" src = "C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/yeezus.jpg" alt = "Kanye" style="width:304px;height:228px">
<div class = "quote">Stay hungry stay. Stay foolish</div>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/my_code.js"></script>
</body> (does not include normal html boilerplate or the stylesheet mentioned in the original question)

Answer (score 1):

It got me stunned for a second too but your problem comes from the semi-colon after .quote class! Remove it and your code will work just fine.

This is how it should look :

```
    .quote {
        background-color: #00FFFF;
        position: absolute;
        height: 50px;
        width: 300px;
        top: 250px;
        left: 500px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #apple{
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
    }

    #random{
        position: absolute;
        top: 500px;
        left: 500px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a syntax error in your css 
        .quote {
        background-color: #00FFFF;
        position: absolute;
        height: 50px;
        width: 300px;
        top: 250px;
        left: 500px;
        text-align: center;
        };

remove this ; and run your code